# Sending email from modal in Django

Tags: python, html, django, email, modal-dialog

I'm trying to create a simple contact form in a modal window and send email to console at the beginning but it doesn't work. I've got everything set.

I've got email backend set correctly as I can send an email from the console.
When opening the modal, the URL of the website is not changing. Does it have something to do with this?

This is what I'm getting in the console

```
[02/Jul/2019 22:30:22] "GET /contact/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1224

[02/Jul/2019 22:30:29] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 2229
```

views.py

```
def email(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            mail = form.cleaned_data["from_email"]
            subject = form.cleaned_data["subject"]
            message = form.cleaned_data["message"]
            send_mail(subject, message, mail, ["example@gmail.com"], fail_silently=False)
            messages.success("Done")
            return redirect("homepage")
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, "home_page/contact_form.html", {"form": form})
```

forms.py

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    from_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    subject = forms.CharField(required=True)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='homepage'),
    path('contact/', views.email, name='contact')]
```

And html

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<h1>Leave me a message</h1>
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <div class="form-actions">
      <button>Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Edit**

Adding code responsible for opening the modal:
home.html

```
<a href="{% url 'contact' %}" rel="modal:open"><i class="far fa-envelope fa-3x"></i></a>
```

Amended action in my contact form, but it's not sending an email and opening the contact form on new page

```
action="{% url 'contact' %}"
```

```
[03/Jul/2019 06:31:30] "GET /contact/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1233
[03/Jul/2019 06:31:37] "POST /contact/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1372
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your form is pointed at your home page instead of the email view. Try changing `action=""` to `action="/contact/"` or for a more proper django way, `action="{% url 'contact' %}"`.

UPDATE:
If the view is getting a `POST` request and sending back a 200, then there's an issue with the code. Try adding an 'else' to the `if form.is_valid()'. It looks now like the form is not validating.

Comment: Just tried that, it's indeed posting the contact form but email is still not sent and it's opening the contact form on another page without any website content.

Comment: Just added else and indeed the form is not valid. What's the best way to check what is failing?